# What does it mean "mounted image is 6.3, not 6.1"

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vmware-esxi, google-cloud-platform

When i upload MY windows 2008 R2 VM have some error :

> Error running workflow: step "translate" run error: step "translate-disk" run error: step "wait-for-bootstrap" run error: WaitForInstancesSignal FailureMatch found for "inst-bootstrap-import-ovf-translate-tran
> slate-disk-vyrpv": "TranslateFailed: Incorrect Windows version to translate, mounted image is 6.3, not 6.1"

How do i fix My command:

```
gcloud compute instances import XXX --os windows-2008r2-byol --source-uri=gs://XXX/XXX/XX-2008R2test01.ovf --zone asia-east1-c
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason Google thinks the Windows image you’re uploading is a Server 2012 R2 one; not a -2008 R2. Whether that’s correct or not I can’t say, but that’s what the error message tells you.

Ref: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Windows_versions